# How can I refresh a grid on tabpanel in ExtJS4

Tags: tabs, extjs4, tabpanel

I have a tabpanel, each tab has a grid. When I click on tab it appears empty. I want grid to be refreshed whenever I click on the tab. How can I achieve this in ExtJS4?

Thank you....

Answer (score 1):

listen for the [`active`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.tab.Tab-event-activate) event on the grid.

and reload the store of the grid if the store is empty